# How to escape single quotes in php for tsql string (ms sql)

Tags: php, t-sql, escaping, single-quotes

how can i escape the single quotes in stuff function? I'm connecting Microsoft SQL with PHP.

```
$hcode = $_GET['hcode'];
$sql = "SELECT AB.HCode, STUFF(AB.Name1,1,6, '') FROM Article AB WHERE Mandant=1 AND Language= 'EN' AND HCode= '".$hcode."' AND AB.Name1 IS NOT NULL";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: explain better you sql code seems right ..  you have errors?

Comment: My mistake i forgot to name the stuff function ... STUFF() AS Name . Everthing is working now

Answer (score 1):

**To escape strings with single quotes for MS SQL, we would need to escape it by adding an another single quote.**

The following function does this. So, you may try using this function:

```
public static function mssql_escape($unsafe_str) 
{
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $unsafe_str = stripslashes($unsafe_str);
    }
    return $escaped_str = str_replace("'", "''", $unsafe_str);
}
//for example $unsafe = "AB'CD'EF";
$escaped = mssql_escape($unsafe);
echo $escaped;// Would output the escaped string as  "AB''CD''EF"
```